# Standalone OpenEJB packaging with dependencies

Tags: openejb

there's some documentation/specification about how to package and deploy EJB with dependencies on OpenEJB?

I tried to deploy an EAR package:

```
service.ear/lib/activemq-all.jar
service.ear/META-INF/application.xml
service.ear/model.ejb!META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
service.ear/model.ejb!com/example/MyActivemqDependentService.class
```

It was deployed successfully, client can find using JNDI, but, when it initialized, NoClassDefFound exception ocurr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ already comes with OpenEJB, I wouldn't expect it to work including it in the EAR as well.

That could very likely be the source of your `NoClassDefFoundError`s.  Removing that `activemq-all.jar` is the first thing I'd try.

Comment: This solve the current problem. I'll test the application for some time and check if this exclusion will not affect some activemq dependent code. Regards

Comment: Should I not be able to ship my own version of any lib I want? I thought that's the idea behind classloader inheritance.

Comment: We actually use a standard `java.net.URLClassLoader` in OpenEJB, so it has the same classloading semantics as a plain Java SE application.  The parent classloader has ActiveMQ in it, so the child classloader can see it and use it.